# Where is the site chatroom?

Tags: support, chat

I can no longer find it [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=law.stackexchange.com).

I think every site has a site chatroom? (And FIRC was called "the courtroom"?)

Answer (score 2):

[The Sidebar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24153/the-sidebar) was frozen for inactivity - I've unfrozen it.